# シェルスクリプトで while ループ内の変更が反映されない

Tags: bash

コマンドの結果を while read でループする様な処理があって
その中で数値を加算する様な処理を追加したんですが
ループ内での変更を反映した結果が取得できません

以下の様なテストコードで再現しました

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=1

echo "2
3
4" | while read i
do
  echo "i=$i"
  ((sum+=i))
  echo "sum=$sum"
done

echo "result=$sum"
```

実行結果

```
i=2
sum=3
i=3
sum=6
i=4
sum=10
result=1
```

ループ内ではきちんと加算されているのにループを出ると1に戻ってしまいます

while read ではなく

```
for ((i=0; i < 10; i++));
```

にかえてみるとループを出ても加算された値が取得できました

なぜこういうことがおこるんでしょうか？

ループ内で加算した数値をループ外で参照するにはどのようにかけばいいのでしょうか

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while以降が子プロセスで実行されているからです。
子プロセスで変数を変更しても親プロセスは関知しません。
※forループの書き方によってはループ内の処理が別プロセスとして実行される場合があります。
ループの内外でプロセスIDを出力(※)してみると異なるPIDになっていることがわかります。
※　echo ${BASHPID}

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=1

echo ${BASHPID}
echo "2
3
4" | while read i
do
  echo ${BASHPID}
  echo "i=$i"
  ((sum+=i))
  echo "sum=$sum"
done

echo "result=$sum"
```

Comment: パイプが悪かったんですね  for i in $(echo "2
3
4")
do と書いたら動きました。while read を使うのをやめてみます

Comment: ご指摘どおり、パイプが原因です。done の後にパイプをつなげても別プロセスとなります。以前デバッグに苦しんだ経験がありました。余談ですが（）で囲んでも別プロセスです。※(( ))とは別の構文です。